# Natural Curve passing through three points

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I want to find the formula to a curve which passes through three points in $2D$. There is no other constraint and the more natural it looks the better, possibly zero tangent derivatives in $p_0$ and $p_2$. It doesn't matter which curve type (quadratic, cubic, etc) we use and the simplest solution that works is the best.

[image]

There are optional properties that would be desirable for a solution:

1. Being able to determine the length of the curve.
2. Determine the $t$ variable at $p_1$.
3. Determine tangents at $p_1$

The points can be colinear.

Comment: You can fit a parabola through three points. You could also look up _cubic spline_.

Comment: You can fit a unique circle through three points

Comment: @EthanBolker OK I'll try that

Comment: @Henry The points can be colinear

Comment: @mortezakhosravi It's often the case that one can consider a straight line to be a special case of a circle. It's often useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is there anything wrong with the unique parabola going through those points? I'll assume you mean three points in general position (no two are colinear.)

In general, you can take $ax^2+bx+c=y$, and use all three points to determine a $3 \times 3$ system of linear equations to solve for coefficients.

In a similar fashion, you could take $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ and again plug in $x,y$ to get a system of linear equations to solve.

1. Both of these should go well, since tangent vectors amount to differentiating second order polynomials, which is easy.
2. The parabola admits the easiest parametrization by $t$ given by $t \mapsto (t,t^2)$, while the circle can be given by $(x,y)=(a,b)+r(\cos t,\sin t)$ which is also not bad to evaluate.
3. Arc lengths will be $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{x^{\prime}(t)^2+y^{\prime}(t)^2} dt$
   which for the parabola is $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$ and for the circle $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{\cos^2t+\sin^2t} dt=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} 1 dt$. Maybe the only caveat is that if you want to find the arc length between *points* you have to find the appropriate $t$ that maps to a point $(x,y)$ but this is not so bad.

Comment: It seems I missed to mention that the points can be colinear.

Comment: In that case, just use a line. The parabola will naturally degenerate when you try to solve it so that $a=0$, and it will just be a line. Maybe that is the easiest way to take care of all cases.

Comment: I don't understand how to parameterize this. Just look at the example I tried to solve https://imgur.com/rvFdJNJ

Comment: I think I have a weak imagination right now, because I didn’t think of this. Two of those points are vertically aligned so no parabola  in general form will pass through them (no function y=f(x) will.) You could still use one, but you would have to rotate the plane get a parabola and rotate back, or something like that.

Comment: I think my nearly horizontal sketch put the vision in the wrong place. Either way this is a great answer and will help other people. Thank you.